# Interpolating string for use in import. Unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs

quick question. This is a snippet of code where I’m trying to use a variable on the import string however I get the error Parsing error: Unexpected token. I’ve tried different ways of joining the base variable and the string together but with no luck.

Is it possible to achieve this kind of join on an import?

I’m looking to save writing out the full URL multiple times as its needed at least 10 times.

I've tried other ways of joining the string but to no avail.

```
const FILE_ROUTE = "../components/study-management/preview/";
import MultieChoice1 from `${FILE_ROUTE}MultieChoice1`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using webpack, you can config `alias` to point to your folder. Such as

```
alias: {
   FileRoute: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/study-management/preview/'),
}
```

then in your code, you can import it like

```
import MultieChoice1 from 'FileRoute/MultieChoice1';
```

Comment: Thanks Tien. Do I need to eject my app in order to do that? I've created this project using CRA.

Comment: Yes, you need to eject it to edit webpack's config.